# Retrieve MongoDB document based on field length using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document with the following format,

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("54a2462820fb5b6068b45b05"),
 "Ref":1,
 "a" : {
   "b" : "value1",
   "c" : "value2",
   "d" : {
   "e" : "value3"
  }
 }
```

}

I need to retrieve the document with length of "e" greater than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use '$where' operator to use javascript and compare string length.

```
db.myCollection.find({'$where':'this.a.e.length > 5'})
```